# Oscillator problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

A material point of mass $m$ is elasticly connected to the origin of coordinates. Communication energy:
$U=(k/2)r^2$,
$k$ - coefficient of elasticity of the bond;
$r$ - distance to origin.
The point was taken at a distance $R$ from the center and released, giving the initial velocity perpendicular to the radius vector. What should be this speed so that in the process of movement the maximum distance of a point from the origin of coordinates is $2R$?

Here, as far as I understand, the point moves in an elliptical orbit in the Hooke field of forces, so even the law of conservation of angular momentum is not needed here - according to the property of the Hooke force field, the projections of the point (unit mass) on all axes oscillate harmoniously on springs with a stiffness coefficient $k$.
Next, we get $mv^2=k(2R)^2$.

Different solutions are possible here, I would like to see options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various aspects that you can exploit, in particular:

1. Easiest option. You can decompose the motion in the $xy$ components, given your special initial conditions the oscillation in the initial velocity direction is out of phase with respect to the initial displacement direction. Then it's easy to see what is the max/min distance from the center.
2. More general option. Consider that, when the orbit is at max distance $r$, the velocity is obviously perpendicular to the radius so it is equal to $L_z/mr$, where $L_z$ is the conserved momentum. Then use the conservation of energy and you get the needed initial velocity.

In all this, you probably want to choose an easy initial position, for instance $\vec{\bf r}(0)=(R,0)$. Remember that this problem is invariant under rotation, i.e. if you rotate the initial configuration, the resulting trajectory will rotate as well... so choose the orientation that is best for you.

Comment: This is a complete answer to a homework-like question, and that is contrary to the goals of the forum which is to facilitate *learning*, not to do homework for people.  It's also supposedly contrary to the rules of P.S.E., but I can't find that written anywhere.  We have to depend on [our friends at Math Stackexchange to get a clear statement on that topic.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/114#114)  Please edit this answer so that it gives direction, rather than a complete answer. (Or delete the answer.)

Comment: Ok thank, sorry I did not know that...